# Rails - Saving in a table and update/creating in another one

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am creating a small app to manage my own online portfolio but I can't solve an issue with `update`.

The main table of my database is `works`, then there's the tables `authors` and `clients` where I set the fields `authorName` and `clientName` as `unique`. Authors and clients can have multiple works, but a work can only have one of each.

In the form where I create works I have a field for the `authorName` and another one for `clientName`: if the author doesn't exist in the authors table it gets created, otherwise the existing one gets linked to the work. Same thing with the client. To achieve this I am using `first_or_initialize` and it works perfectly. Problems start when I try to use the same method inside the `update` action. These are my models:

**Work Model**

```
 class Work < ApplicationRecord

    has_one :description

    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :client

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author

    scope :active, lambda {where(:isActive => true)}
    scope :descOrder, lambda {order(:date => :desc)}
    scope :cover, lambda {where(:isCover => true)}

end
```

**Author Model**

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :works

end
```

**Client Model**

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :works

end
```

*Quick edit: the models as you see them are exactly as they are in my app. No code has been removed.*

This is the form in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@work, :url => { :controller => "projects", :action => "update"} ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label("title") %>
    <%= f.text_field(:title) %>

    <%= f.fields_for(:author) do |author| %>
        <%= author.label("author") %>
        <%= author.text_field(:authorName) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for(:client) do |client| %>
        <%= client.label("client") %>
        <%= client.text_field(:clientName) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label("date") %>
    <%= f.date_field(:date) %>


    <%= f.submit("update") %>
<% end %>
```

And this is how I am handling it in the controller:

```
def edit
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])

  if @work.client.nil?
    @work.build_client
  end

  if @work.author.nil?
    @work.build_author
  end
end

def update
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])

  @work.client = Client.where(clientName: work_params["client_attributes"]["clientName"]).first_or_initialize
  @work.author = Author.where(authorName: work_params["author_attributes"]["authorName"]).first_or_initialize

  if @work.update(work_params)
    flash[:notice] = "work: #{@work.title} updated successfully."
    redirect_to(project_path(@work))
  else
    redirect_to new_project_path
  end
end

private

def work_params
  params.require(:work).permit(:title, :date, client_attributes: [:id, :clientName], author_attributes: [:id, :authorName])
end
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Started PATCH "/projects/21" for ::1 at 2019-10-14 20:00:27 -0700
Processing by ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"rw3X7VJg8CDnOibniv1jKHTVTGp7pjE4ep6xHpHy0Zp8Xv/0uQd6y5xqq629M2FOOQNoYyOAXH//w5/VoeNEOA==", "work"=>{"title"=>"Progetto1", "author_attributes"=>{"authorName"=>"Autore1", "id"=>"34"}, "client_attributes"=>{"clientName"=>"Cliente4", "id"=>"30"}, "date"=>""}, "commit"=>"update", "id"=>"21"}
  Work Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `works`.* FROM `works` WHERE `works`.`id` = 21 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:42:in `update'
  Client Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`clientName` = 'Cliente4' ORDER BY `clients`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:44:in `update'
  Author Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `authors`.* FROM `authors` WHERE `authors`.`authorName` = 'Autore1' ORDER BY `authors`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:45:in `update'
Completed 404 Not Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 3805)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Client with ID=30 for Work with ID=21):

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:47:in `update'
```

Even though those record **do** exist in the database (with those IDs that you see in the error) and their foreign keys are correctly stored in the `works` table (I checked in mysql).

What I am expecting to achieve is the same behaviour of the `new` action (that I described in the beginning of my post).

How can I solve this? Thank you!

---

*Small update*: if I change `first_or_initialize` with `first_or_create` it does create the author (or client), if not existing, but in the same time it still gives me the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't mix camel case and snake case. Stick with snake case when working in Rails; it'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Can you post full code from the `Work Client Author` classes?

Comment: @anothermh thanks for the advice, I'll follow that.

Comment: @DimitriusLachi these are the whole models for each of them, there's nothing else inside, it's a really simple app (plus I want to make sure all the relationships work without problem before adding anything else)

Answer (score 0):

After dozens of tests I eventually came up with a sort of solution - it's not "elegant" and probably it's not the best, but at least it works without interruptions:

```
 def edit
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])

    if @work.client.nil?
      @work.build_client
    end 

    if @work.author.nil?
      @work.build_author
    end

  end

  def update
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])

    @work.client = Client.where(clientName: work_params["client_attributes"]["clientName"]).first_or_create
    @work.author = Author.where(authorName: work_params["author_attributes"]["authorName"]).first_or_create

    if @work.update(update_params) 
      flash[:notice] = "work: #{@work.title} updated successfully."
      redirect_to(project_path(@work))
    else
      redirect_to new_project_path
    end

  end

private

    def work_params
      params.require(:work).permit(:title, :date, client_attributes: [:id, :clientName], author_attributes: [:id, :authorName])
    end

    def update_params
      params.require(:work).permit(:title, :date)
    end
```

Being that `first_or_initialize` works smoothly with `save` method, but it gets stuck - at least in my code - with `update`, I replaced it with `first_or_create`.

This time, however, I am using another private method `update_params` which simply ignores `:client_attributes` and `:authors_attributes`.

This results in an `Unpermitted parameters: :author_attributes, :client_attributes` error, as expected, but at least everything goes through and gets updated.

Honestly I am not quite sure that I totally understood why it's working. But it does.

Anyway, if anyone have a better solution to this problem I am totally open to improve it.